React Native Expo Web deployment
I'm creating a phone application with react native as part of a tech stack, but I also want to deploy a web version of my app through Netlify.
How would I go about doing this?
I have realised that with React, you can create a build with npm run build, which will be used on Netlify, but this is not the case with react native. How can I create a build with react native.
